# How to get MAC address and channel info with Native Wifi API C++

Tags: c++, windows, wifi

I have this:

```
WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST *wlanNetworkList = (WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST*)WlanAllocateMemory(sizeof(WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST));
```

and I get info about networks with WlanGetAvailableNetworkList() function.

But in this info there aren't mac address or channel.
How to get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the information you're looking for is in the `WLAN_BSS_ENTRY` structure.

As there might me more than one access points for a network, it makes at least sense to me that there is not a single MAC address for a network (also consider ad-hoc networks) and therefore, the MAC address is not part of the properties of the network (is no data member of the `WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK` structure).

Using `WlanGetNetworkBssList` ([msdn library entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) you can get a list of BSS entries for a specific network (by passing the SSID) or for all networks of a wireless LAN interface. Note this function queries the access point:

> The list of information returned for each wireless network also contains a list of information elements returned by each access point for an infrastructure BSS network or a network peer for an independent BSS network (ad hoc network).

---

By the way: I think you don't need to allocate a buffer for the `WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST` structure with `WlanAllocateMemory`. MSDN:

> The buffer for the WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST returned is allocated by the WlanGetAvailableNetworkList function if the call succeeds.

Yet, you have to free the memory the function has allocated for the list via `WlanFreeMemory`.

See also the [example in msdn library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (bottom of that page).

Edit: the example is a bit confusing, there's a variable called `pBssList` which is of type `PWLAN_AVAIBLE_NETWORK_LIST` and not `PWLAN_BSS_LIST` as the name suggests.

Comment: Ok thanks, but now I have another problem, if I do something like that: 

while(1){
...
WlanGetNetworkBssList(...)
...
Sleep(5000)
}

Only works for the first time, the other times all the values in the bssList are 0.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me (periodically calling `WlanGetNetworkBssList`) on Windows 7, so it would require some more context of your call to guess where the problem resides. This would be another question, besides.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you will try first use WlanScan.
I try write WlanApi in assembly, goasm.
I use WlanGetNetworkBssList.
Everything Work, in return i get 6 bytes of mac but only first 3 is the same like Mac my router. I don't understand why. Maybe I'm write wrong sruct in WlanApi.h
I'm still studing  ASM
[WlanApi.h](http://wklej.org/id/1259379/)
[MyCode](http://wklej.org/id/1259380/)